# Server.Transfer in C# code. Server does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

I'm making a method that will be called from a webpage, which uses [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer) to  terminates execution of the current page and starts execution of a new page.

However, since the method I'm making is not an aspx page, Service Studio complains about the Server instance not existing in current context.

How can I circumvent this?

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do is post some code and explain a bit more about where the call to `Server.Transfer` actually is in your code.

Comment: Keep the code you are using in aspx.cs file itself. Is this used across different pages? If yes, show some code for someone can assist with redesign.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current` (`System.Web.HttpContext class defined in System.Web`)

Even if you are developing class library for web application you can reference and use it.

you would need `HttpContext.Current.Server` but you may find other useful data there too.